# How to solve this question and how to increase php programming level

Tags: php

Recently i have see this questions, but i don't understand how to solve.

```
1 3. The first three elements of the array are {3,1,5}.
After first operation: {2,0,4}. Now as one element becomes 0, we start decreasing the entire array.
After second operation: {1,0,3,5,2,1,8}.
After third operation: {0,0,2,4,1,0,7}.
After fourth operation: {0,0,1,3,0,0,6}.
...
After tenth operation: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}.
```

How to increase my php skill level then i can beat this and harder then this problem.
And thanking you to for help : )

Comment: I assume this is homework or a job interview related question.. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to determine what the initial state of the array was, or create a routine that operates on arrays in order to produce such a result?

Comment: Yes this is job interview question. But I need what practice I do for this types of questions

Answer (score 0):

The code below will achieve what you are trying to do.

```
<?php 

//example array
$arr = [ 12, 15, 0, 4, 7, 2, 4, 7, 2, 1 ];
//get length of array so you don't have to do it in the while/for loops (less operations)
$len = count( $arr );
//get max value in the array
$max = max( $arr );

while ( $max !== 0 ) {
//iterate through the array $max number of times
//so that in the end all values within the array have
//been decreased to 0
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ ) {
    //if the value of array is not 0, reduce it by 1
        if ( $arr[ $i ] > 0 ) {
            $arr[ $i ] = $arr[ $i ] - 1;
        }
    }
    $max--;
}
?>
```

Comment: How to practice for this type questions

Comment: You could set up a local testing environment with WAMP/XAMP. Then all you need to do is think of similar problems and write php scripts for them and test them as you work with them. I would also suggest reading php documentation to get a deeper understanding of the language. That will most likely give you ideas on how you could solve the same problem in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of doing this.

Simple for loop:

```
<?php
$input = [3,1,5,5,9,7,2,11];

do
{
    for ($i=0;$i<count($input);$i++)
    {
        if ($input[$i] > 0)
        {
            $input[$i]--;
        }
    }

    $uniqueValues = array_unique($input);
    $uniqueCount = count($uniqueValues);
} while($uniqueCount>1 || ($uniqueCount==1 && $uniqueValues[0]>0));
```

foreach loop

```
<?php
$input = [3,1,5,5,9,7,2,11];

do
{
    foreach ($input as &$currValue)
    {
        if ($currValue > 0)
        {
            $currValue--;
        }
    }

    $uniqueValues = array_unique($input);
    $uniqueCount = count($uniqueValues);
} while($uniqueCount>1 || ($uniqueCount==1 && $uniqueValues[0]>0));
```

array_walk

```
<?php
$input = [3,1,5,5,9,7,2,11];

do
{
    array_walk($input, function(&$currValue){
        if($currValue>0)
        {
            return $currValue--;
        }
    });

    $uniqueValues = array_unique($input);
    $uniqueCount = count($uniqueValues);
} while($uniqueCount>1 || ($uniqueCount==1 && $uniqueValues[0]>0));
```

As far as how to "practice" for questions like this... just write a lot of code and read the documentation.